# Why getting different data in browser developer tools vs BeautifulSoap / Postman?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, postman

I want to scrap data from this web page

I want to get all the blogs...which are under result tag `(<div class="results">)`

In browser tools there it is showing under result tag there are 10 snippets...
[image]

But using Beautifulsoap I am getting

```
<div class="results">
</div>
```

and in postman getting same thing..

This is the way I am doing..

```
topicuri = "\"
r = s.get(topicuri)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
pages = soup.find('div', {'class': 'results'})
print(pages)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also can get data from api calls json response

```
import requests
import json 
body= "vodafone"
headers= {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
   }

api_url = "https://search.donanimhaber.com/api/search/portal/?q=vodafone&p=3&devicetype=browsermobile&order=date_desc&in=all&contenttype=all&wordtype=both&daterange=all"

jsonData = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers).json()

for item in jsonData['contents']:
    categoryName=item['categoryName']
    print(categoryName)
```

Output:

```
Operatörler - Kurumsal Haberler
Operatörler - Kurumsal Haberler
Operatörler - Kurumsal Haberler
Mobil Aksesuarlar
Operatörler - Kurumsal Haberler
Kripto Para
Sinema ve Dizi
Mobil Oyunlar
Operatörler - Kurumsal Haberler
Operatörler - Kurumsal Haberler
```

Comment: Thank you @F.Hoque..your answer is super helpful...One more thing how to get  all the comments that are in the bottom of this page https://www.donanimhaber.com/vodafone-da-yuzde-100-online-basvuru-donemi-basladi--146295   Can we get this?

Comment: Comment data aren't produced from  the url that you've asked as json response but also json response but  data is in html dom. So to aget all comment data you have to use your comment url to grab data from api calls json response that's why you can create another question using your comment url.

Answer (score 3):

The website is using Javascript to display the snippets. BeautifulSoup does not execute Javascript, while the browser does. You will probably want to use the Chromium engine in Python in order to web-scrape Javascript-based content.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `requests` could not render `JavaScript` but there are two alternatives:

- Use `requests` and perform a post request on your url
- Use `selenium` to get the rendered `page_source` as you would expect it.

#### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://search.donanimhaber.com/portal?q=vodafone&p=3&devicetype=browsermobile&order=date_desc&in=all&contenttype=all&wordtype=both&range=all'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './/div[@class="results"]/div[@class="snippet"]')))

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")

pages = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'snippet'})

for p in pages:
    print(p.h2.text.strip())
```

#### Output

```
Vodafone'dan dijital sağlık projelerine ücretsiz 5G desteği
Vodafone'un son 15 yılda Türkiye ekonomisine katkısı açıklandı
"Yarını Kodlayanlar" projesinde gençler afet sorunlarına çözümler üretti
Küresel akıllı saat pazarı yılın ilk çeyreğinde yüzde 35 büyüdü
Vodafone Türkiye'nin ilk çeyrek sonuçları açıklandı: Servis gelirlerinde yüzde 19 artış
Netflix'e yeni eklenen dizi ve filmleri takip edebileceğiniz site
Sony ve SinemaTV anlaştı! Spider-Man, Venom 2 ve daha fazlası TV'de ilk kez SinemaTV'de yayınlanacak
Vodafone ve Riot Games, Türkiye'nin ilk 5G Wild Rift turnuvasını duyurdu
Türkiye'de kaç kişi numara taşıma ile operatör değiştirdi?
Turkcell'in Ramazan'a özel Salla Kazan kampanyası başladı
```